# Fb Comments Doesn't load on Jquery click

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

The code works fine if put in php and refreshed but i want it to be loaded on click of a div( say #F1) . But on applying it via a jquery + json request, It does'nt show up... Here is the code for

```
//Loading On click Event
$('#F1').click(function(e)
    {
        //alert('1');
        loadData3();
        FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('divfbcomment'));

    });


//loadData3() definition
var loadData3 = function(){
      var url = 'commenter.php';
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $('#levelsel').empty().append(data.selS);
        $('#fbc').empty().append('<div class="fb-comments" id = "divfbcomment" data-href="mysite/comment/comment'+data.fbS+'" data-width="650" data-numposts="3" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>');
      });
}

//Commenter.php
<?php 
session_start();
//echo $_SESSION['level'];
$selstring=''; 
$selstring.='<select class="sel">';
          for ($x=$_SESSION['level'];$x>0;$x--)
               $selstring.='<option>Level&nbsp;'.$x.'</option>';
$selstring.='</select>';

$data=array();
$data=array(
'selS'=>$selstring,
'fbS'=>$_SESSION['level'],
);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

My O/P is as follows

```
<div class="fb-comments" id="divfbcomment" data-href="mysite/comment/comment3" data-width="650" data-numposts="3" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

It doesn't load the required document....

Sorry if it's a duplicate, We didn't get the required answer....

---

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle ?

Comment: It worked when  FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('divfbcomment')); was put in callback function :)